# Add attribute to my angularjs custom directive and lets its value listen to same directive model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a custom directive, however I want that directive to get an attribute injected into it and elements within that directive to change the that directive's attribute values. 
Here's the code:

Ultimately I want my directive to look like this:

```
<joe-grid viewedtable="table1"></joe-grid>
```

table1, table2 etc.. will all change based on the selected option from the dropdown.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('joeGrid', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<select name="myTables" id="myTables" ng-model="mytable"><option value="table1">table1</option><option value="table2">table2</option><option value="table3">table3</option><option value="table4">table4</option></select><h1>Hi there, it is me: {{adjective}}  </h1>',
    scope: {
      adjective: '@viewedtable',
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$set('viewedtable', '{{mytable}}');
      // I want to viewtable attribute to be equal to ng-model=mytable 
    }
  }
});

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<joe-grid></joe-grid>
```

Comment: `viewedtable="table1"` indicates that you're passing some object from the current scope called "table1", then in your directive you've set it to be called "adjective". So you have whatever "table1" is inside your directive. What is table1 though? /is/ it an object?

Comment: viewedtable={{mytable}}, table1 is one of the options in the select dropdown within the same directive. whenever the user selects any, it can be table1 2 3 etc..

Comment: @tenCupMaximum here's the way the directive is <joe-grid></joe-grid> in this link: https://jsfiddle.net/joeSaad/3refx09g/

Comment: Not clear what you want to achieve (otherwise it would have already be answered, because I'm sure this is simple). Try to explain better what you want.

Comment: within my custom directive, I create an attribute dynamically (viewedtable), however the values of viewedtable should be binded to ng-model="mytable". Trying to achieve this in an expression viewedtable={{mytable}} using the $set method, doesn't seem to work. How do I bind the values of that dynamically created attribute to model within the same directive? Hope this made it a bit clearer.

Comment: What do you mean "create attribute dynamically" when I see that you have `<joe-grid viewedtable="table1"></joe-grid>` with the attribute already in place?

Comment: I think this is the cause of confusion. I pointed out that ultimately this is how I want the HTML to look like. It is not like that originally. it's only <joe-grid></joe-grid> attribute is not there yet.